# How can I create a stream with an array of the value of other streams?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a structure like that:

```
+----o---->
+------------o---->
+-o---->
+------------o---->

mergeAsync()

+----------------->[o, o, o, o]
```

I'm searching the way of concat the value of some streams in an array, I tryied to merge, concat or zip the result, but I don't want to create a new stream with the merge/concat/zip.

[jsbin code snippet](https://jsbin.com/buqesi/edit?js,console)

Do you know any clean way to do this?

```
const log = (stream) => {
  return stream.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    e => console.log(`onError: ${e}`),
    () => console.log('onCompleted')
  )
}

let m$ = Rx.Observable.range(99, 140).take(3)
const $1 = Rx.Observable.range(0, 10).take(3)

m$ = Rx.Observable.merge($1, m$).toArray()

log(m$)
```

Comment: Is working perfectly for me, probably a version of jsbin? @praveen-kumar. I add the code on the post

Comment: toArray only yields values when the source stream is complete. Is this want you want? Or do you want to re-emit a new array of values each time something is added to the source stream?

Comment: Yes, the toArray is exactly what I don't want I guess.

Comment: Yes, publish the array in a new stream, and keep adding streams like $1 or m$ into that, and still adding it into the new stream inside the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be after something like this:

```
var ss$ = new Rx.Subject();

const s1$ = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3);
const s2$ = Rx.Observable.range(10, 3)

ss$
  .switch()
  .scan((a, c) => {
    const newArray = a.slice();
    newArray.push(c);
    return newArray;
  }, [])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

ss$.onNext(s1$);
ss$.onNext(s2$);
```

https://jsbin.com/fidowo/edit?js,console,output

ss$ is a subject of observables, and you can push new observables to it. Each of these observables is a stream of numbers, and each time a new element is added to any of the streams, a new array is emitted that contains all values. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Yeah, sounds great. I undestand the point of having Subject instead of Observables, because you can onNext values on the stream, and it's exactly fine.

Comment: The only thing that I miss, it's the switch, what's doing exactly?

Comment: switch "flattens" an observable of observables into an observable. It does this by pushing all the elements that come in on any of the observables into the same resultant observable. It has nothing to do with the regular switch statement in javascript, no matter what SO's syntax highlighting says :)

Comment: What happen if s1$ instead of Observable are Subjects or Behaviour?

Comment: Both Subject and BehaviorSubject are also observables; what determines the differences here is whether the observables are "hot" or "cold". Subject is "hot", so anything pushed to a Subject before the Subject is pushed to ss$ would be lost. BehaviorSubject is... "warmish"... it will replay its last value, but anything before that would be lost. Observable.range is "cold", so subscribers receive all the values at the moment of subscription. Lee Campbell's "Introduction of Rx" covers this topic... it's well worth a read.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I didn't know the real difference between Subject and BehaviourSubject.

Comment: I invite you at gitter, it's the chat for github users, just in case that you want to join and talk about some Rx stuff ^^

Answer (score 0):

I can probably solve this using zip like:

```
const log = (stream) => {
  return stream.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    e => console.log(`onError: ${e}`),
    () => console.log('onCompleted')
  )
}

const s1 = Rx.Observable.of({key: '$1'})
const s2 = Rx.Observable.of({key: '$2'})
const s3 = Rx.Observable.of({key: '$3'})

let m$ = Rx.Observable.zip(s1, s2)

log(m$)
```

I remove the range and I use objects instead (and `.of`, but I could use `.return` or whatever), because doesn't make sense on the case.

But eventually, I want to add the `s3` stream into the `m$`, and I'm not sure how do this...

Comment: zip will only yield values when a new value is available on all zipped streams. Is this what you want?

Comment: no, exactly what I wanted is what Matt Burnell suggest.